# Flutter - The best way to parse a JSON

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I'm trying to parse JSON to an object in Dart, the documentation uses Map type to parse a JSON response.I have about 200 list on data form json file.

My result data to list of all record and render it to ListView in flutter.
I have push code in github. https://github.com/phuochoit/user_list

```
[
  id,
  name,
  username,
  email,
  phone 
]
```

JSON

```
 {
      "type": "user",
      "format": "json",
      "version": "1.0",
      "data": {
        "Sincere@april.biz": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Leanne Graham",
          "username": "Bret",
          "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
          "address": {
            "street": "Kulas Light",
            "suite": "Apt. 556",
            "city": "Gwenborough",
            "zipcode": "92998-3874",
            "geo": {
              "lat": "-37.3159",
              "lng": "81.1496"
            }
          },
          "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
          "website": "hildegard.org",
          "company": {
            "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
            "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
            "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
          }
        },
        "Shanna@melissa.tv": {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Ervin Howell",
          "username": "Antonette",
          "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
          "address": {
            "street": "Victor Plains",
            "suite": "Suite 879",
            "city": "Wisokyburgh",
            "zipcode": "90566-7771",
            "geo": {
              "lat": "-43.9509",
              "lng": "-34.4618"
            }
          },
          "phone": "010-692-6593 x09125",
          "website": "anastasia.net",
          "company": {
            "name": "Deckow-Crist",
            "catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency",
            "bs": "synergize scalable supply-chains"
          }
        },
.... to be continued
      }
    }
```

I have code get json file and decode it in dart but i not map data to render

```
Future<UserModel> fetchUser() async {
      final response = await http.get('http://172.16.0.2/data/users.json');
    
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
        // then parse the JSON.
    
        return UserModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
      } else {
        // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
        // then throw an exception.
        throw Exception('Failed to load album');
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Compare this with things like quicktype**: (1) If you do not have a model class, then try to use things like quicktype to get that class from a sample json string. (2) However, I suggest not to use the `toJson` and `fromJson` given by quicktype. The reason is that, when your model changes (say add a field / change a field), you *must* also change your toJson/fromJson accordingly (which is time-consuming and error-prone). Otherwise you get a bug.

If you already have your model class and only need the `toJson` and `fromJson` methods: Then the very famous [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) package suits you. It will happily generate the `toJson` and `fromJson`.

For example, say you have

```
class Person {
  final String firstName;
  final String lastName;
  final DateTime dateOfBirth;
}
```

Then with a bit of boilerplate code, it will auto give you

```
Person _$PersonFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return Person(
    firstName: json['firstName'] as String,
    lastName: json['lastName'] as String,
    dateOfBirth: DateTime.parse(json['dateOfBirth'] as String),
  );
}

Map<String, dynamic> _$PersonToJson(Person instance) => <String, dynamic>{
      'firstName': instance.firstName,
      'lastName': instance.lastName,
      'dateOfBirth': instance.dateOfBirth.toIso8601String(),
    };
```

Actually that package is more powerful than that. Check out the link for more details.

Comment: Thanks you. I wil reading json_serializable and try again.

Comment: @phuochq You are welcome. If this answer helps you, you can mark it as "accepted"

Comment: Hi you, I used it but I'm having problems. I cannot use the data due to an error 
`Instance of 'ListUser', Instance of 'ListUser'`.
please clone github of my. I push new code here
[link](https://github.com/phuochoit/user_list)

Comment: @phuochq show you full stacktrace & error please

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a JSON model generator, don't waste your time in reinventing the wheel.

I used https://app.quicktype.io/ it's awesome, input JSON, it will create Dart classes, piece of cake, really!

For example for this JSON :

```
    [{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5968dd23fc13ae04d9000001"
  },
  "product_name": "sildenafil citrate",
  "supplier": "Wisozk Inc",
  "quantity": 261,
  "unit_cost": "$10.47"
}, {
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5968dd23fc13ae04d9000002"
  },
  "product_name": "Mountain Juniperus ashei",
  "supplier": "Keebler-Hilpert",
  "quantity": 292,
  "unit_cost": "$8.74"
}, {
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5968dd23fc13ae04d9000003"
  },
  "product_name": "Dextromathorphan HBr",
  "supplier": "Schmitt-Weissnat",
  "quantity": 211,
  "unit_cost": "$20.53"
}]
```

It generated this model in Dart:

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final welcome = welcomeFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

List<Welcome> welcomeFromJson(String str) => List<Welcome>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Welcome.fromJson(x)));

String welcomeToJson(List<Welcome> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Welcome {
    Welcome({
        this.id,
        this.productName,
        this.supplier,
        this.quantity,
        this.unitCost,
    });

    Id id;
    String productName;
    String supplier;
    int quantity;
    String unitCost;

    factory Welcome.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Welcome(
        id: Id.fromJson(json["_id"]),
        productName: json["product_name"],
        supplier: json["supplier"],
        quantity: json["quantity"],
        unitCost: json["unit_cost"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "_id": id.toJson(),
        "product_name": productName,
        "supplier": supplier,
        "quantity": quantity,
        "unit_cost": unitCost,
    };
}

class Id {
    Id({
        this.oid,
    });

    String oid;

    factory Id.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Id(
        oid: json["\u0024oid"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "\u0024oid": oid,
    };
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: `Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "Sincere@april.biz": sincereAprilBiz.toJson(),
        "Shanna@melissa.tv": shannaMelissaTv.toJson(),
    };`
Thanks you. It gives me this code. I think if I put all the data in it will be very large and the client's email will be made public. This is not good