# How to convert Json to form in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, forms, api

I need help in converting a JSON returned from an API into a form. I have gone through some libraries on `pub.dev`, but they all seem not to support null safety, and I am using flutter 3.0. Here is the link to the JSON object: `https://pastebin.com/z0fngaJr`

Comment: I would advise you to check out the following, and improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/62571582/16974425

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter - The best way to parse a JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65518198/flutter-the-best-way-to-parse-a-json)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no null save package that converts it directly. I think you have to use something like the [convert library](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.1/dart-convert/dart-convert-library.html) and then you can fill the retrieved data into your form. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15866290/the-best-way-to-parse-a-json-in-dart) you can also find further information.

If null safety is not important for you [this](https://github.com/VictorRancesCode/json_to_form?ref=morioh.com&utm_source=morioh.com) package could be interesting.

Comment: Thanks @maxmitz but the above json_to_form library does not work for me